# Set img src from an input box with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, src

I'm trying to set the `img src` based on the value of an input box with jQuery:

```
<img class="preview" id="img" src="">    
<input id="form" placeholder="skin URL">
```

This is the javascript code:

```
$("#form").change(function(){
$("#img").attr("src", $("#form").val());
});
```

I don't know why is not working. What's wrong?

EDIT: Now it works but i set a cookie on the input box so when i refresh the page the img only loads when input box loses focus(with .blur()). I want the img to always load automatically. Any tips?

Comment: have you written .change() event in $(document).ready?

Comment: Works fine for me!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/498ygw4q/ seems fine but its not working

Comment: you have not added jquery file to fiddle

Comment: try: https://jsfiddle.net/ec76k0vp/

Comment: How can i load the img src when the page is loaded. I'm asking it cuz i set a cookie on the input box so the link stay there when i refresh

Comment: $("#img").attr("src", $("#form").val()); on document.ready...outside of change() event..

Answer (score 1):

This might help you,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#form").blur(function(){
          var inputVal = $(this).val();
          $("#img").attr("src", inputVal);
     });
});
```

Comment: Good job. Another question: i set a cookie on the input box so when i refresh the img only loads when input box loses focus. I want the img to load automatically

Answer (score 1):

You  Can try this

```
<img class="preview" id="img" src="">    
<input id="form" placeholder="skin URL">    

$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#form").keyup(function(){
          var inputVal = $(this).val();
          $("#img").attr("src", inputVal);
     });
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Ramkee/45cxqfb6/2/)**

Answer (score -2):

Code is OK and working fine for me. 
May be jQuery script file is not referenced correctly
and check image url you are trying to set on img